# Material UI - Change Dialog Container

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to pass/change a container to material ui components like Dialog, Popper and so on? (https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/) They render the popup on document.body

The purpose is to be able to show the dialog from within a shadow dom

```
export default class MyWebComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
        this.mountPoint = document.createElement("span");
        this.mountPoint.className = "inner-app";
        this.reactRoot = shadowRoot.appendChild(this.mountPoint);
    }

  connectedCallback() {
    const jss = create({
      ...jssPreset(),
      insertionPoint: this.reactRoot,
    });

    render(
      <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
        <SimpleDialogDemo />
      </StylesProvider>,
      this.mountPoint
    );
  }
}

customElements.define("my-web-commponent", MyWebComponent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Dialog supports all of the properties of [Modal](https://material-ui.com/api/modal/#props) including the `container` prop. [Popper](https://material-ui.com/api/popper/#props) also has a `container` prop.